# Unable to write logs to my log file using log4j for Selenium

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am unable to write to the log files using Logger in log4j. I am initialising the log4j2.xml file to the custom path as follows:

```
@BeforeClass
    public void initLogger()
    {
        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\log4j2.xml";
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", path);
    }
```

I think the `log4j2.xml` is correctly picked up because System logs are correctly written to the log file. However I am not able to write custom logs to the log file. The test class and method are as follows

```
public class ValidateHeading extends BaseClass {
    
    
    public static Logger log=LogManager.getLogger(ValidateHeading.class.getName());
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void initLogger()
    {
        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\log4j2.xml";
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", path);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void validateHeading() {

log.info("Something");

 }

}
```

The log4j2.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">./logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="Files" fileName="${filename}/prints.log" filePattern="${filename}/print-%d{dd-MM-yyyy hh.mm}.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Files" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is the log4j2 xml in classpath? Are there any console logs or any debug logs?

Comment: The log4j2.xml is within a resources folder. I get the following log `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Academy.ValidateHeading).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.` @aksappy